# meaning of "I would suggest that you don't do it"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the meaning of "I would suggest that you don't do it". Is it a piece of advice or a guess? Or can it mean either?

For example:

(suggestion)

> -- Should I go to "Starbucks" today?
>
> -- Well, **I would suggest that you don't do it**. Too many people there. You'll be standing in a long line.

(guess)

> -- So how do you, guys, think I earn this money? Do you think I take some hourly job, or win it in lottery, or beg for it on the streets?
> What do you think? Or, perhaps, you think that I regularly rob small
> stores?
>
> -- **I would suggest that you don't do it**. There are other, more possible ways of how you get that money.

Comment: The verbs *guess* and *suggest* are not synonymous. I suggest that you provide further context, without it the question may be closed for lack of research.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Webster says that "suggest", among other meanings, has the meaning "to offer for consideration or as a hypothesis": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggest , which is pretty much the same as "guess". What further context you mean? This question has long been on my mind, but I don't have any specific context besides what I described in the question.

Comment: If someone suggests that you visit an elderly relative who is unwell that is neither a guess nor a hypothesis. If you ask what treatment a diseased plant should have, you may receive *several suggestions*, in other words "solutions" or "ideas", depending on the number of people you ask and their level of expertise. If someone is particularly convinced by one of the suggested treatments, they might **recommend** a particular pesticide. Again nothing to do with the meaning of guess.

Comment: If someone suggests that you leave the diseased plant alone and not use any treatment because plants fend for themselves, I might say: "**I'd suggest that you don't do that** because the plant could die.”

Comment: @Mari-LouA - On one hand, you said "_... you may receive several suggestions, in other words "solutions" or "ideas"_", and yet, on the other hand, you  say "_nothing to do with the meaning of guess_". If someone provides his idea about the possible reason how or why something happens (like in my example), that IS a guess, or an act of guessing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You seem to have totally ignored the word "hypothesis" in that Webster's definition that I gave you.

Comment: No, offering an array of  solutions is *not* synonymous with *guessing*. It is providing a possible "cure". The person may not have the *answer* and the solutions could be prompted  by past experiences or ideas on how best to go forward. They are only  **pieces of advice** (hypotheses) which the listener can choose to either ignore or accept. That M-W use the term hypothesis to explain the meaning of suggest does not mean that guess and suggest are synonymous. What does a thesaurus say?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "array of solutions"? Why array??? I said "provides his idea about the possible reason", I didn't say "provides an array of ideas". If someone provides his idea on the reason why something is happening, that is his hypothesis and yes, this is also his guess on why something is happening.  "_does not mean that guess and suggest are synonymous_" - I never said they are synonymous. However, at least one meaning of "suggest" (that is, to provide a hypothesis) overlaps with "guess". On the other hand, "advice" and "hypothesis" are not synonymous at all!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "_What does a thesaurus say?_" Here is the thesaurus for "hypothesis": https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hypothesis . Note the word "guess" in there. And here is the one for "suggest": https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/guessed . Note the word "suggest" in there.

Comment: A piece of advice could be based on a hypothesis. Have it your way, I suggest that you look at several other dictionaries and read their definitions. [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/suggest) is good for providing sample sentences. P.S **It might be a good idea to edit you post and explain it was inspired by the M-W definition**. At least it will explain to users your confusion... or not.

Comment: Your second example is nothing to do with guessing. To guess is to invent an answer when you don't know all the facts, not to give advice to someone else.

Comment: @KateBunting - My second example has nothing to do with giving advice.

Comment: Then don't use "I would suggest that you..."!

Comment: @KateBunting - I used "I would suggest that..." in that example in the sense of "I would suppose that..."

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You would have to say "I don't suppose [that] you will do any of those things."