# "I suggest that you ... = I guess(suppose) that you ..." - May it be true in some contexts?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In some dictionary I encountered the next sentence

```
I suggest that you had a secret understanding
```

It is quiete clear that *suggest* have meaning *suppose/guess* there.

But I have heard that this meaning is incorrect: [meaning of "I would suggest that you don't do it"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295796).
Is it really true? If we accept the second meaning like *suppose/guess* then how to deal
with ambiguities like:

```
I sugges (guess) that you have a secret understanding 
I sugges (propose) that you have a secret understanding
```

Answer (score 1):

A 'suggestion' is, most commonly, some helpful information that you impart to somebody else. In this case, however, it is more like an *accusation*. The speaker is proposing (putting forward for consideration) their belief or opinion about the other person. It is a slightly formal use of the word, but it is in line with dictionary definitions.

Comment: So, the ambiguity at the end of my question (I propose/suppose that you have a secret understanding) is really possible?

Comment: @xyz Yes, I'd agree that 'propose' is a reasonable definition. It's rather like when you hear in a courtroom statements like "*I put it to you* that you killed your husband". They are *suggesting* what the person did, rather than putting something to them that they don't know. "Suppose" has a more nonchalant meaning, though, so I wouldn't use that word in its place - it doesn't sound certain.

Comment: I meant that: "I suggest (propose) that you have..." = "I advise you to have". Is this meaning possible? If so, is it ambiguity with "I suggest (guess) that you have..."

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific style implied by your example:  A lawyer, in court, questioning a witness.

It isn't really a "guess" or "supposition", but more of a proposition for the witness to agree with or refute.

The past tense form ("you *had*) means that this isn't advice for the future.